Detect patterns in html dom
I have this html document which I have parsed via anglesharp HtmlParser.
I now want to be able to deteck certain patterns in this html document based on how the body.childnodes are ordered.
to do so i've defined some patterns
var pattern = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    {"TextComponent", new List<string>() { typeof(IHtmlHeadingElement).Name, typeof(IHtmlParagraphElement).Name } },
    {"TextComponent1", new List<string>() { typeof(IHtmlParagraphElement).Name }}
};
    

and then sorted them
var sortedPattern = pattern.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Count).ToList();

    

Then I iterate through the list of patterns, to see whether I find a match,
// Iterate through the sorted dictionary
foreach (var kvp in sortedPattern)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {string.Join(", ", kvp.Value)}");
    var windowSize = kvp.Value.Count;
    var childNodes = document.Body!.ChildNodes;
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.Length; i += windowSize)


      {
            var window = childNodes.Skip(i).Take(windowSize).ToList();
            var windowMatches = window.here(node => kvp.Value.Contains(typeof(name).Name));

            if (windowMatches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"window matched with {kvp.Key}");
            }
        }
    }

The problem here is the order of the matches I get.
Ideally i would want to check all patterns within the same window so the first pattern it checks is  the largest one and then the smaller and smaller ones)
so I can keep track with the order of where the patterns are recognized in the html dom.
